# data wrangling with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I get a 2d numpy array as an output after each for loop for processing multiple data files.

I intend to stack all 2d numpy arrays every time one loop ends. At the end, I want to get only one 2d numpy array which contains the average of all 2d arrays.

For instance, if I get following arrays after 2 loops,

```
arr1 = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
arr2 = np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3, 3)
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

I want to get the following array as a final output (outside of the for loop).

```
array([[5.5, 6.5, 7.5],
       [8.5, 9.5, 10.5],
       [11.5, 12.5, 13.5]])
```

I'd appreciate any idea how to (to which direction) stack 2d arrays so that I can obtain the final output with the average.

If there is an ambiguity, I'm happy to provide more backgrounds.

Comment: I don't see any "stacking".  You have two (3,3) arrays, and want a (3,3).  I'm guessing you want to do some sort of calculation with `arr1` and `arr2`, but what isn't obvious from the desired result.  Do you want the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `dstack`?

```
np.dstack([arr1, arr2])
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1, 10],
        [ 2, 11],
        [ 3, 12]],

       [[ 4, 13],
        [ 5, 14],
        [ 6, 15]],

       [[ 7, 16],
        [ 8, 17],
        [ 9, 18]]])
```

For the average:

```
np.dstack([arr1, arr2]).mean(2)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 5.5,  6.5,  7.5],
       [ 8.5,  9.5, 10.5],
       [11.5, 12.5, 13.5]])
```